# Adding an object to a arraylist inside a nested for loop

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to loop a JSON array to an array list Category and a nested Arraylist SubCategory.

My problem is that my list not only gets populated with the first SubCategory data, but also the second SubCategory data.

For example, I want:

```
1st category [Apple, Kiwi] 
2nd category [Mango, Banana]
```

But instead I get,

2nd category populate as `[Apple,Kiwi,Mango,Banana]`.

```
ArrayList<Category> categoryName=new ArrayList<Category>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<SubCategory>> subCategoryName = new ArrayList<ArrayList<SubCategory>>();
ArrayList<Integer> subCategoryCount = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

ArrayList<SubCategory> subCategoryMatches = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
try {
    // Parsing json array response
    // loop through each json object

    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject allCategory = (JSONObject) response
                .get(i);

        int id = allCategory.getInt("mcatid");
        String description = allCategory.getString("description");

        Category categoryDetails = new Category();
        categoryDetails.setCatCode(id);
        categoryDetails.setCatName(description);
        category_name.add(categoryDetails);

        //Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(description));

        JSONArray  allSubCategory = allCategory
                .getJSONArray("Subcatergory");

        for (int j = 0; j < allSubCategory.length(); j++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = allSubCategory.getJSONObject(j);

            String subCatId = jsonObject.getString("id");

            String subDescription = jsonObject.getString("description");

            // retrieve the values like this so on..

            //Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(subDescription));


            SubCategory subCategoryMatch = new SubCategory();
            subCategoryMatch.setSubCatName(subDescription);
            subCategoryMatch.setSubCatCode(subCatId);
            subCategoryMatches.add(subCategoryMatch);

        }

        subcategory_name.add(subCategoryMatches);
        subCatCount.add(subCategoryMatches.size());
    }
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but I won't read this either.  It is up to _you_ to explain your problem clearly to us.  Do you really need all that code?  Maybe not, but in any case you should highlight where the problem is.

Comment: You seem to already have two POJO classes... Why not use Gson or Jackson to parse this all for you?

Comment: [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

Comment: @MehmanBashirov The actual documentation might be better. https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding to the same `subCategoryMatches` list reference, and so you'll get all data within one object.

You need a new list prior to the loop that adds to it.

```
ArrayList<SubCategory> subCategoryMatches;

try {
    // Parsing json array response
    // loop through each json object

    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
        ...

        // New list
        subCategoryMatches = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();

        // Loop and add
        for (int j = 0; j < allSubCategory.length(); j++) {
            ...
            subCategoryMatches.add(subCategoryMatch);
        }

        // Add new list to outer list
        subcategory_name.add(subCategoryMatches);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am a android beginner  plz tell me exactly where i have to create that list and how to add the items to it. thanks

Comment: You already have this exact code. The `...` is the removed code after the loop with the exact same signature. The `new ArrayList<>` goes on the line previously, as I've already written. I'm not going to copy your whole code just to show the differences

Comment: when i put subCategoryMatches = new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
 above the allSubCategory for loop app crashes when i click on category

Comment: Well, that sounds like a different problem entirely. No part of your question includes a click listener

Comment: plz check the screen shots.. https://ibb.co/iOqmbk
https://ibb.co/jtvKwk

click listener works for my code. after apply your changes error comes

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to tell me. Add the logcat to your initial post, not a screenshot of a random UI

Comment: how to logcat arraylist data?

Comment: `Log.d("list", String.valueOf(list))` ? That's not what I meant, though. Your app crashes. What does it says `Caused by` ?